# OpenCSV reader for Java - how to get the number of columns?

Tags: java, opencsv

I have OpenCSV reader in a Java project and its reading data from CSV files for me, but right now Im hardcoding the number of colums in the loop that reads it.
I can recall there was some method that could get the number of columns but I dont remember what it was called and how to use it.

Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCSVContent(String filepath) throws Exception {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        String[] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //5 is the number of columns in the file 
                list.add(nextLine[i]);
            }
            array.add(list);
        }
        reader.close();
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the items in the array with `nextLine.length`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) { 
  list.add(nextLine[i]);
}
```

Or use a for-each loop:

```
for (String col : nextLine) {
  list.add(col);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a easy way is that you read the first line with a Scanner of BufferedReader and count the ";" or what you use to split the columns.

You are able to count it if you use

```
string.toCharArray();
```

and ++ a Integer if it is ';'.

A second way is the look at the methods of CSV Reader. I don't know them but you can type anywhere in eclipse(don't know how it works in netbeans) "reader." and press control + space. If you have luck there is one.

Comment: This is a poor answer. Firstly, you suggest that a hand-crafted solution is tried rather than using a library. This is rarely a good idea, especially with CSV parsing. Secondly, you don't provide an actual answer but rather suggest that auto-completion may help. On the whole, not very helpful.

Comment: Yes I write this answer because he didnt find a getColumnCount Method. My answer is 100% correct I know that it isnt better than a library. I just want to help so hes able to program. Idk what you mean that I dont provide a answer. It would be work so? The auto completion was a tip from me and not a solution.

Comment: You have to be careful counting the delimiters. You also need to take into account that there may be escaped delimiters within the CSV column text.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one to get the column count: [`reader.getColumnCount()`](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html#getColumnCount%28%29)

Comment: Im getting a red underline and this error The method getColumnCount() is undefined for the type CSVReader

Comment: Are you using this library                                             http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/?source=directory

Comment: No, Im using OpenCSV. not Java CSV.

Comment: maybe I should try nextLine.length but I can't right now because I broke my code elsewhere... :)

Comment: I down-voted because the OP is using a different library (as stated in the question).